# Why shouldn't you use objc_msgSend() in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

The Objective C Runtime Guide from Apple, states that you should never use objc_msgSend() in your own code, and recommends using methodForSelector: instead. However, it doesn't provide any reason for this.

What are the dangers of calling objc_msgSend() in your code?

Comment: Because it will cause the end of the Universe as we know it.  And will be impossible to decipher 6 months from now, especially if someone else is reading the code.

Comment: Because it's like if you disassemble a mountain bike, and use it's wheels and singular pieces to move around.

Comment: (And if you do use it, comment the hell out of it.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Reason #1: Bad style - it's redundant and unreadable.

The compiler automatically generates calls to `objc_msgSend()` (or some variant thereof) when it encounters Objective-C messaging expressions. If you know the class and the selector to be sent at compile-time, there's no reason to write

```
id obj = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend([NSObject class], @selector(alloc)), @selector(init));
```

instead of

```
id obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

Even if you don't know the class or the selector (or even both), it's still safer (at least the compiler has a chance to warn you if you are doing something potentially nasty/wrong) to obtain a correctly typed function pointer to the implementation itself and use that function pointer instead:

```
const char *(*fptr)(NSString *, SEL) = [NSString instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(UTF8String)];
const char *cstr = fptr(@"Foo");
```

This is especially true when the types of the arguments of a method are sensitive to default promotions - if they are, then you don't want to pass them through the variadic arguments `objc_msgSend()` takes, because your program will quickly invoke undefined behavior.

## Reason #2: dangerous and error-prone.

Notice the "or some variant thereof" part in #1. Not all message sends use the `objc_msgSend()` function itself. Due to complications and requirements in the ABI (in the calling convention of functions, in particular), there are separate functions for returning, for example, floating-point values or structures. For example, in the case of a method that performs some sort of searching (substrings, etc.), and it returns an `NSRange` structure, depending on the platform, it may be necessary to use the structure-returning version of the messenger function:

```
NSRange retval;
objc_msgSend_stret(&retval, @"FooBar", @selector(rangeOfString:), @"Bar");
```

And if you get this wrong (e. g. you use the inappropriate messenger function, you mix up the pointers to the return value and to `self`, etc.), your program will likely behave incorrectly and/or crash. (**And you will most probably get it wrong,** because it's not even that simple - not all methods returning a `struct` use this variant, since small structures will fit into one or two processor registers, eliminating the need for using the stack as the place of the return value. That's why - unless you are a hardcore ABI hacker - you rather want to let the compiler do its job, or there be dragons.)

Comment: It is important to emphasize that `objc_msgSend()` -- the varargs base function -- is not compatible with a strongly typed method call.  Which is why casting **is required** when using `objc_msgSend()`.   Which is also exactly why you should avoid it as much as possible.  As soon as you cast an expression, you are basically telling the compiler that you are smarter than it, which is rarely the case.

Comment: @user529758 It's faster and only errors if the system swipes your memory. Not validating a pointer as your implying is never a good idea. Plus, the code is objc_msgSend([NSObject class], @selector(alloc)), @selector(init); not objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend([NSObject class], @selector(alloc)), @selector(init)); But you're using the the class method so you just negated all benefits of using 0bjc_msgSend. the correct way is "(*p_objc_msgSend)( p, mySelector);" And that code is pasted from how a call is made in ARC.

Comment: Also #2 is great example of how not to program. You  have experience with pointers you never do that, also don't write 1 liners. You verify address exists and call immediately. You also use pointers and validate pointers. The example you pasted in #2 makes 4 calls to objc_msgSend for FooBar and Bar. The point of calling it specifically is performance, but your example waste performance benefits.

Answer (score 11):

You ask "what are the dangers?" and @H2CO3 has listed some ending with "unless you are a hardcore ABI hacker"...

As with many rules there are exceptions (and possibly a few more under ARC). So your reasoning for using `msgSend` should go something along the lines of:

[ 1] I think I should use `msgSend` - **don't**.

[2] But I've a case here... - *you probably haven't, keep looking for another solution*.

...

[10] I really think I should use it here - **think again**.

...

[100] Really, this looks like a case for `msgSend`, I can't see any other solution! OK, go read `Document.m` in the [TextEdit code sample from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html). Do you *know* why they used `msgSend`? Are you sure... *think again...*

...

[1000] I understand why Apple used it, and my case is similar... You've found and *understood*  the exception that proves the rule and your case matches, **use it**!

HTH

Comment: I will now have to think about why they used `objc_msgSend()` directly in that piece of code. I'm also surprised it's called immediately *after* the disposal of ownership (`release`). Maybe it's just that it's 10PM here, but I don't really get it, in fact.

Comment: If you need to send a message with an arbitrary selector and non-`id` arguments, you can't use `performSelector:…`.  You can either use `objc_msgSend` or you can use `NSInvocation`.  Using `objc_msgSend` is substantially simpler.

Comment: That code is unfortunately magical.   Bugs will be filed to remove the magic at the cost of a few more lines of penetrable code.

Comment: @bbum - Magical? First time I ever heard anyone call TextEdit that ;-)

Comment: @H2CO3 If you find the reasons, please share them

Comment: @robmayoff why not `instanceMethodForSelector:` and a function pointer then?

Comment: @Sulthan Sample code, in general, is documented.  TextEdit is less sample code and more a reference implementation of the state of the art Cocoa app.   To that ends, it is more complex and atypical than most samples.   Still, that particular construct could be better expressed.

Comment: @H2CO3 That would work too, and you wouldn't have to worry about which version of `objc_msgSend` to use, but you'd still need to specify the signature of the function, just as you do with `objc_msgSend`, and the compiler still wouldn't be able to check that you've specified the right signature.  It would be better if `NSErrorRecoveryAttempting` specified a method taking a block instead of a selector.  (The protocol predates blocks.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Actually, after reviewing the implementation of [`instanceMethodForSelector:`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm), I'm not sure that method does save you from the `_stret` problem.  The method always calls `class_getMethodImplementation`, but the runtime also provides `class_getMethodImplementation_stret`, which returns a different value when the message will be forwarded.  Seems like `instanceMethodForSelector:` is broken in that case.

Comment: This discussion revolves around engineering solutions to a created problem. It is interesting to ask how can a C compiler construct an appropriate call to a function pointer? Why can't it do the same for a selector? Type erasure... (a thorn to ARC as well) Anyway, over here at the Unseen Uni the TextEdit code is not magical; it's simple, direct & clear for the context - and I expect the same solution is used in similar contexts elsewhere. @H2CO3, maybe you should ask not why the `release` is there, but why the `retain` is - but is this not an orthogonal issue? Happy ruminating to all :-)

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks. Now that's interesting. Actually, I'd have expected that the returned function pointer is called differently (and hence correctly, according to the ABI) when cast to the correct function pointer type... I mean can't the compiler just deduce whether to look for the return value in r0 or eax if the return type is an int and pop it off of the stack when it's declared to be a struct?

Comment: You use it for performance to avoid the 16 calls that Arc makes for one instruction. Unless you're an advanced programer it should be avoided. Typically I use it when I have a widely used function that is fast and logic is isolated.

Answer (score 4):

I can make a case. We used msgSend in one of our C++ files (before we switched to ARC) that's in a cross-platform project (Windows, Mac and Linux). We use it to ref count a reference in the backed (the shared code) that's used later to go from frontend to backend and vice versa. Very special case, admittedly.