# Objective C - Passing a float through a selector

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to pass a float through a selector using 'withObject:' however, it only accepts objects.

There are solutions that tell me to use [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ]  however it's messing with the value of my float. I am doing a before and after testing of the values of the float, and beforehand I get numbers such as 0.0034324, whereas afterwards they are all 0.0000000

```
[[self gameObjects] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(update:) withObject: <what to put here>]];
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT***

here is the context

```
-(void) tick:(float)dt{
    NSLog(@"%f",dt)
    [[self gameObjects] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(update:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dt]];

}
```

The number outputted from above is NOT 0

But from the selector method....

```
- (void)update:(float)dt{

    NSLog(@"%f",dt);

}
```

The output is 0

Comment: Can you show the example where you were seeing 0.0000000? You should fix that, because wrapping the float in an NSNumber is the right answer. You just made some mistake in the implementation of it.

Comment: Indeed; it's a safe bet that if you think you were getting 0.00000 then you were taking the `floatValue` of `nil` rather than of an actual number.

Comment: Show the declaration for `update:`. What is the parameter type? It can't be of type `float` since you need to pass it an `NSNumber`.

Comment: That's not possible this way because Objective-C [doesn't perform autoboxing](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/01/does-objective-c-perform-autoboxing-on-primitives/). You either have to do this yourself in an other method, use [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or use the method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17263420/1592765)

Comment: NSNumber *will not* "mess" with the value of your float, if you do it right.  The problem is that you're not *receiving* an NSNumber in your target method, but rather trying to interpret a pointer to an NSNumber as a float.

Comment: Thanks for the update showing more of your code. It helps when trying to dissect the problem and offer advice. Also, you should accept the best answer when you think you've found one. Doing so will make people more inclined to help you in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with primitive types in Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904515/how-to-use-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-primitive-types-in-cocoa) Answer? Use `NSInvocation`.

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap the float in an NSNumber.

```
NSNumber * num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.5];
```

**EDIT:**
As rmaddy has pointed out, here are some other ways to use NSNumber *

```
NSNumber * num = @5.5f;
float someFloat = 5.5f;
NSNumber * num1 = @(someFloat);
```

To OP,
We need to see more of your code to help dissect the actual problem

**Update to respond to new context**

In your target method you are specifying that you expect a (float) as the expected argument. It is important to be cognizant of the type of variable you are passing to functions. Notice the last argument to your makeObjectsPerformSelector method is prefaced as withObject. This indicates you are passing an object, not a primitive float. So wrap the float you want to pass in an NSNumber as such:

```
NSNumber * numToPass = @(floatToWrap);
[[self gameObjects] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(update:) withObject:numToPass]];

- (void)update:(NSNumber *)dt {

    NSLog(@"%f",dt.floatValue); // or [dt floatValue];

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Even easier: `NSNumber *num = @5.5;` or `NSNumber *num = @(someFloatVariable);`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, you've made some mistake in your attempt to use `NSNumber`s and would probably be better off asking us to look at that code.

I ran the following:

```
float value = 0.0034324f;
NSNumber *valueObject = @(value);

NSLog(@"%0.7f, %@", value, valueObject);
```

Output was:

```
2013-07-12 17:45:07.948 Untitled[4950:707] 0.0034324, 0.0034324
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't change my selected method to accomodate an NSNumber, as it still had a float as its parameter type.

Thanks for the help everybody.

Comment: You should accept the best answer here. Doing so will make people more inclined to help you in the future. You have many open questions with no selected answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self gameObjects] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(update:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dt]];
```

Calls a selector that has a float argument. 
Chang the update: argument to NSNumber and inside it call floatValue on the NSNumber

Probably better to just do a for-in loop on your array of gameObjects than all this performSelector and NSNumber business. In the loop call the update netheid directly.

Comment: *Calls a selector that has a float argument.* - No, that code calls a selector that has an `NSNumber` argument.

Comment: Yes, the OP's `update:` selector takes a `float`. But your comment appears to refer to the line of code in your answer. That line of code attempts to call a selector that needs to take an `NSNumber` argument. That's the point of my comment. Your answer seems to claim that the line of code in your answer is calling a selector that takes a `float` argument.

Comment: Forgot to copy paste the rest. The other bit though still calls that selector. Passing the object to it may indeed give you a zero float.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `NSInvocation`. It's not the most pleasant thing to write, but it does exactly what you asked for:

```
- (void)update:(CGFloat)value
{
    XCTAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(value, 2.1, 0.001, @"");
}

- (void)testNSInvocationOverArrayWithFloatArgument
{
    CGFloat value = 2.1;
    NSArray *gameObjects = @[ self ];

    for (id object in gameObjects) {
        NSMethodSignature *signature = [object methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(update:)];
        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];

        [invocation setTarget:object];
        [invocation setSelector:@selector(update:)];
        [invocation setArgument:&value atIndex:2];

        [invocation invoke];
    }
}
```