# Switch IPAD to IPAD AIR Error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x384e344432212301)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, afnetworking

I'm desperating,
i have an IOS App that is running well on IPAD,IPAD 2 and even on an IPAD Air Simulator, but trying to run this APP on an IPAD AIR Device the App crashes while making an HTTPS Request and fetching some data.
for the HTTPS Request I use the AFNetworking Framework.
Has Anyone an Idea or some Experience with simular problems ?
I have already read a lot articles on stackoverflow and was trying to look for a Zombie, but nothing found.

```
- (void) executeRequestType:(RequestType)type_
              requestMethod:(RequestMethod)method_
                     layout:(NSString *)layout_
                     action:(NSString *)action_
                 parameters:(NSDictionary *)params_
               successBlock:(SuccessBlock)success_ {

    _status = RequestStatusInitate;

    //NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@", layout_, params_, action_);
    NSString *parmstr = @"";
    if (params_) {
        parmstr = [self parmeterStringFromDictionary:params_];
    }
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=%@&-lay=%@%@&%@",SERVER_URL,DB_NAME, layout_, parmstr, action_];
    NSLog(@"request str %@", strURL);

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    if (method_ == RequestMethodDelete) {
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
    }

    AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation
                                        XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {

                                            NSLog(@"%li",(long)response.statusCode);

                                            NSObject *object = success_(XMLParser);
                                            NSString *requestType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", type_];
                                            NSDictionary *responseDict;
                                            responseDict = @{ DATA: object,
                                                        REQUEST_TYPE: requestType};
                                            _status = RequestStatusCompleted;
                                            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                                            objc_msgSend(_delegate, @selector(callerDidFinishLoading:receivedObject:), self, responseDict); 
        //Trying to call "callerDidFinishLoading" EXC_BAD_ACCESS is Thrown
    }
                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {

                                            _status = RequestStatusCompleted;
                                            NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                            objc_msgSend(_delegate, @selector(caller:didFailWithError:), self, error);
                                            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                                                                                           }];

    [operation start];


    _status = RequestStatusInProgress;

}
```

Comment: The compiler should be warning about that bare use of objc_msgSend().

Comment: I am new to this project and there a lot of Warnings. Cannot take the time to fix every Warning :/

Comment: Sunk cost fallacy. :)  Over time, I guarantee you'll be wasting more time trying to wade through warnings to find the new ones with meaning vs. the time invested fixing them.   I fully sympathize with your position on this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `objc_msgSend` to call the delegate method?

You need to change:

```
objc_msgSend(_delegate, @selector(callerDidFinishLoading:receivedObject:), self, responseDict);
```

to:

```
[_delegate callerDidFinishLoading:self receivedObject:responseDict];
```

If it's an option delegate method then do:

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callerDidFinishLoading:receivedObject:)]) {
    [_delegate callerDidFinishLoading:self receivedObject:responseDict];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it solve my problem, but i still can't see the big difference. And I can't understand why it run well on older IPad 1+2, but crashed on IPad AIR ??

Comment: Found an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263354/why-shouldnt-you-use-objc-msgsend-in-objective-c